# При уменьшении размера экрана, уменьшаеться картинка. min-width i min-height не помогают

Tags: html, css, frontend

когда размеры экрана доходят до 70, картинка (она находиться в хедере) начинает сильно уменьшаться. При этом, все остальное, а это кнопка логина и сама навигация остаються на месте.

вот размеры 970:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а вот 950:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот HTML код:

```
<div class="header-logo"><img src="img/logo-4.jpg" alt="Logo" class="logo"></div>
```

а вот css код:

```
@media (max-width: 960) {
.logo {
    min-height: 37px;
    min-width: 60px;
}

.header-logo {
    min-height: 37px;
    min-width: 60px;
}

.header-login {
    height: 10px;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку автор поленился привести код отображенных картинок, то предположу что элементы меню выстраиваються через `flex-box` Для того, что бы были минимальные значения картинок лучше не указывать  `min-width` а зафиксировать размены картинки через `width:60px; display:inline-block;` или же `width:100%; max-width:60px` а єлементу навигации задать `width:100%;`